# memoir \setfloatadjustment does not work after loading fixltx2e

Tags: floats, memoir, incompatibility, fixltx2e

Consider the following snippet:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\setfloatadjustment{figure}{\raggedleft}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
ABC
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

When you compile this code, one would expect that `ABC` would be placed on the right side of the typeblock but instead it is placed on the default side (left).
After commenting out the fixltx2e package, the code works as expected. Unfortunately some package that I use loads the fixltx2e package so I cannot simply comment out the usepackage. Does someone know how to fix this issue? It seems that `\@xfloat` is overwritten, but this should have been covered by memoir by the lines:

```
\AtBeginDocument{
  \let\m@m@xfloat\@xfloat
  \def\@xfloat #1[#2]{%
    \m@m@xfloat #1[#2]%
    \def\baselinestretch{\m@m@float@spacing}%
    \normalsize}
}
```

Comment: It works for me. Can you update your distribution and try again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, [`fixltx2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fixltx2e) overwrites `\@xfloat`. The assumption is that it fixes content in the standard document classes, of which [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) is not.

Since `memoir` manages things on its own, best would be to save-and-restore the `memoir`-specific version of `\@xfloat`, or just redefine it:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\makeatletter
% Restore original memoir definition of \@xfloat
\def\@xfloat#1[#2]{\mem@old@xfloat{#1}[#2]\@nameuse{#1adjustment}}
\makeatother
\setfloatadjustment{figure}{\raggedleft}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
ABC
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Note that `fixltx2e` will form part of the LaTeX2e (upcoming TeX Live 2015) release by default:

> LaTeX2e now incorporates, by default, changes previously included only by explicitly loading the `fixltx2e` package, which is now a no-op ([CTAN announcement](http://latex-project.org/ltnews/ltnews22.pdf)).

Comment: Isn't the normal way if loading fixltx2e to load it before the documentclass. In the fix you are doing here mem@old@xfloat will refer to the memoir xfloat before fixltx2e

Comment: @daleif Normally, you would be right to load fixltx2e before the documentclass, but there are some packages that are not compatible (like asmthm).

Comment: Since the material in fixltx2e is going into the kernel amsthm is going to be updated if it haven't already